# Printing backslashes in exec()

Tags: php

I've figured out how to print `\` to the page with an echo command using

```
echo '\\';
```

This fails when used inside the `exec()` function. I'm trying to issue this command to the command line to run csvkit:

```
csvclean -q \" -e ascii  -z 10000000000000 file.csv
```

Unfortunately, I have to throw in `"` to specify my variable. I believe that as it is, the `"` is being escaped properly, but nothing seems to help me get a `\` printed.

This is what I've attempted:

```
exec("csvclean -q \" -e ascii  -z 10000000000000" . " " . $csvfilename );
```

Comment: Have you tried `csvclean -q \\\" -e ascii  -z 10000000000000 file.csv`? Also, can you show how you are actually calling `exec`?

Comment: I'm using this:

     exec("csvclean -q \" -e ascii  -z 10000000000000" . " " . $csvfilename );

Comment: If you need `\"` literally, change the quotes to an apostrophe. Ie. `exec('csvclean -q \" -e ascii -z 10000000000000  ' . $csvfilename );`

Comment: THANK YOU!! Both your solutions work inside the exec() function. Add it as an answer so I can make it official :)

Comment: You're welcome, and done. Glad I was able to help. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, in answer form. ^^

Since you need both `\"` literally within the `exec`, you can do one of two things:

```
exec("csvclean -q \\\" -e ascii  -z 10000000000000 " . $csvfilename );
```

Or, easier, is to use apostrophe's to make everything inside literal and not need to be escaped.

```
exec('csvclean -q \" -e ascii -z 10000000000000 ' . $csvfilename );
```

Answer (score 6):

use `addslashes` function:

```
echo addslashes('csvclean -q " -e ascii  -z 10000000000000 file.csv');
```

output:

```
csvclean -q \" -e ascii -z 10000000000000 file.csv
```

**Edit:**

to fire a command do this:

```
exec('csvclean -q \" -e ascii -z 10000000000000 ' . $csvfilename );
```

Comment: This prints to screen, I need it to fire command line program.